# how to create a php fatal error and a php parse error?

Tags: php

I need 2 php errors, fatal and parse, so I can test my logrotate configuration because I saw that after logrotate configuration the error_log file still empty and I would like check

Thank you

Comment: try error_log function http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Catchable fatal error**

```
<?php echo new stdClass();
```

**Parse error**

```
<?php echo .....
```

**Notice** and **Warning**

```
<?php echo A / B;
```

**Deprecated**

```
<?php mysql_connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two PHP files for that, as each error will stop execution.

Shouldn't be too hard to create a parse error:

```
<?PHP
{
?>
```

And a fatal error is similarly easy to provoke:

```
<?PHP
noSuchFunction();
?>
```

Was that your question?

Answer (score 0):

Call an undefined function for a Fatal error, and a syntax error for a Parse error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>
> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'